# Закрытие модульного окна

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Может кто-то пожалуйста подсказать как закрыть модальное окно после клика на кнопку отправить форму.

```
    $(function() {
    $('button.btn-lg').click(function() {
        var parent = $(this).attr('data-parent');
        var modal = $(this).attr('data-target')
        $(modal).find('input[name=target]').val(parent);
    })
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('[data-submit]').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('form').submit();
    })
    $.validator.addMethod(
        "regex",
        function(value, element, regexp) {
            var re = new RegExp(regexp);
            return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
        },
        "Please check your input."
    );


    function valEl(el) {

        el.validate({
            rules: {
                tel: {
                    required: true,
                    regex: '^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$'
                },
                name: {
                    required: true
                },
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                tel: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                    regex: 'Телефон может содержать символы + - ()'
                },
                name: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                },
                email: {
                    required: 'Поле обязательно для заполнения',
                    email: 'Неверный формат E-mail'
                }
            },

            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $('#loader').fadeIn();
                var $form = $(form);
                var $formId = $(form).attr('id');
                switch ($formId) {
                    case 'popupResult':
                        $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: $form.attr('action'),
                                data: $form.serialize(),
                            })
                            .always(function(response) {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $('#loader').fadeOut();
                                }, 800);
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    $('#overlay').fadeIn();
                                    $form.trigger('reset');
                                    //строки для остлеживания целей в Я.Метрике 
     и Google Analytics
                                }, 1100);
                                $('#overlay').on('click', function(e) {
                                    $(this).fadeOut();
                                });

                            });
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }

        })
    }
    $('.js-form').each(function() {
        valEl($(this));
    });
    });


------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
    labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
    label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="success.php" class="js-form" id="popupResult">
                <input type="text" name="target">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Имя">
                 <input type="text" name="email" required placeholder="Введите 
    E-mail"  class="form-control form__field">
                    <input type="text" name="tel" required placeholder="Введите 
    телефон"  class="form-control form__field">
                <button type="submit">Отправить</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
   dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$("#myModal").hide();`

Comment: Igor а куда его вставит что бы сработал при этом loader и overlay?

Comment: @Викто в код вставляйте!

Comment: Понятно что в код. Лучше подсказал бы куда именно его вставить. После кода валидации он не работает

Answer (score 0):

добавь в форму в хтмл атрибут `onsubmit="hideModal()"` и опредилите эту функцию в js:

```
function hideModal(){
$("#myModal").css({'display': 'none'});       //выбери
$("#myModal").css({'visibility': 'hidden'});  //один
$("#myModal").fadeOut();                      //вариант
$("#myModal").hide();                         //из этих
```

Comment: и правда, давайте весь js код писать отдельно, а вот вызов одной функции сделаем в лучших традициях 2000-х годов пропишем в атрибут формы